# Leaflet map on click ignore layers

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Leaflet has a ['click' event](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#events):

```
map.on('click', function(e) {
  alert(e.latlng);
});
```

This does not appear to work when map layers are displayed on the area clicked. Is there a way to use `map.on('click')` so that it ignores any layers on the map?

Answer (score 1):

When you have a layer that **also** listens for click then it will pick up the top most layer's event.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asnyder14/ao2dsqwp/).

You can add the shape click handler and see that it picks that up instead of the map's.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. This is the problem I am trying to solve-  I want to avoid having to manually set up the click handling for each layer (my map has 8+ layers). Thanks again.

Comment: @Matt: you could create custom events on the layers (`layer.on("myEvent",function(e){...});`) and trigger them in the `click`-event callback of the map (`layer.fire("myEvent");`)

Comment: Layers inherit from `Evented` - so follow e.g. https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/core/Events.js

Answer (score 1):

If you do (or want to) use the [Leaflet 1.0 Beta](http://leafletjs.com/2015/07/15/leaflet-1.0-beta1-released.html) version, Marker and Path have an `interactive` option.

> If false, the marker will not emit mouse events and will act as a part of the underlying map.

(from [leaflet beta API](http://mourner.github.io/Leaflet/reference.html))

Comment: In Leaflet 0.7 it [also seems to exist](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-clickable), it is called `clickable`